# <tr> <td>click</td> <td>//div[3]/div/a/span</td> <td></td> </tr> on selenium

Tags: selenium-ide

I have  got this error while using selenium IDE. I have this project where I was testing. After record button this error was shown on my IDE..

```
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>//div[3]/div/a/span</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

Please help me to find this solution.

Comment: What was the error specifically?  Was it element not found? What was the action you were expecting?

Comment: element was not found.

Comment: If you're going to reference an error message you should probably include it.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the element wasn't actually there yet, just add a waitForElementPresent command before the click command.

waitForElementPresent | //div[3]/div/a/span |

Comment: If that was the issue. the IDE has a nice "find" button you can use to check to see if that is valid XPath.